# Upload file from directoy path

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm trying to upload a file on an android phone using HTML5 and Javascript. Everything works perfectly except the phone asks the user to select an app to find the file. Is there a way to skip the app selection, and force the user to select a file from the Chrome Downloads directory?

Additional Info: I am able to skip the app selection when the user downloads the file by using "data:application/octet-stream;Content-Disposition:attachment". Is there something similar for uploading a file?

Comment: It appears to me that this question is *not* about uploading a file without the user's consent, but only allowing a user to select files (for uploading) that are 'stored' in a specified (local) directory. Edit: one *can* do this in IE using javascript *with* the co-operation of the user who must enable the path-resolver option, but this is not about IE...

Comment: You are correct Gitaar. The browser on the phone that I am using is Chrome.